# How to change element id dynamically using js

Tags: javascript

I am not using `jQuery`, I want to get all the elements that has an `id` attribute equal to `app`, and loop over those elements in order to assign a new unique id per elements.

For example, I have these `<div />`:

```
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="app"></div>
```

All have the same `id`.

I want to make them unique by add `app-1`, `app-2` `app-3` dynamically.

How can I do this using Vanilla JS?

**For those who may need to know why? well it was for instantiating vuejs instances in the same page with same ids. I was trying to it in wp elementor widget. I was able to instantiate the widget with one vue instance but it failed when I dropped the same widget. so I needed to change id of the instance dynamically. Here are the code which will definitely help you all**

```
<nice>
<div id="app" class="app">
{{ message }}
<h1  v-for="(l,i) in lists" :key="i">{{l.name}} {{i+1}} </h1>
</div>
</nice>
```

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("nice");

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].setAttribute("id", "app-" + i);
        var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app-" + i,
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue!', 
            lists: [{name: 'wow this is cool'},{name: 'wow this is cool'},{name: 'wow this is cool'},{name: 'wow this is cool'}],
        }
        })

    }
</script>
```

Comment: `All are same ids`. Id should be unique, try to use class instead

Comment: From where are you getting these divs?

Comment: Thanks. Let me try with class@Tân

Comment: That's a very long different story. I want to make something else works. to make that work I needed the id to be different on the fly. so that's the problem

Comment: Have a check on my answer, it tells you how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying where the divs are coming from is important here because you should be using class instead of id's since id's are to be unique.

To answer your question specifically and if you can't change the id's, then the below will use the the tag name to complete the task you need.

**updated:** removed button to clearly demonstrate update

```js
  var list = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
 
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

    list[i].setAttribute("id", "app-" + i);

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


  <div id="app">A</div>
  <div id="app">B</div>
  <div id="app">C</div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should not bind javascript into HTML, it's a bad practice. Instead, use `document.addEventListener`, because currently you are mixing the concernes. Also, html is a case insensitive language, there's no point of using `DIV` uppercase. Lastly, in web you can now use backticks instead of concatenating string using `+`. Check my answer.

Comment: You are currently looping over all the html and then adding ids to all html.. I want to change ids to unique only where we have id = 'app' and change them to app-1 , app-2

Comment: that's what I did in my answer, have you checked the 2nd code sample below the 1st code sample ?

Comment: The button was just for demo purposes for the OP. Removed it - still does the same thing.

 

It doesn't loop through all the html Shakil. It loops through div elements as your initial question has only div elements. Add another tag (<p> for example) and you'll see the ID isn't attributed.

Comment: Thanks. You were targeting all divs in the dom, so I changed it to a custom tag such as nice and then it targeted only nice. Thank you. Solution is working.

Comment: This solution is less elegant than  mine. It's old code (old loop, old string concatenation, odd selector). But take what you prefer

Comment: Don't know why people downvoted but I can bat many people is trying this.. I have edited my question with the full code with your solution. Thank you.

Comment: Code readability is more valuable than fanciful code. I do like your solution! However, a forEach loop, backticks and shortcut selector isn't enough value to supercede readability imo. @DimitriKopriwa

Comment: @Zedkay22 that's because you have a few experience, but trust me, now everyone write recent JS code for the one reason that it is more readable. Otherwise, why adding those in ES6 and ES7 as a so called `improuvement` ? Check yourself on GitHub.

Comment: Also, the `forEach` takes a callback, directly, which means it gives you best pratice to handle the loop as a singular function treatment.  I only see a few reason why you would use a `for` loop, and one of them is for using `async/await ` inside the loop. Which is also ES6/ES7. You can keep writing vanilla old school JS, but that's not the way to do it in 2020. It's still good to know it.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute `id` must have unique values in an HTML page, which means you can't have more than one in the same page.

You want to use `class` which can have many of the same names, check this example:

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('app')]
  .forEach(($app, i) => $app.classList.add(`app-${i+1}`));
```

```css
.app {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.app-1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.app-2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.app-3 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="app"></div>
<div class="app"></div>
<div class="app"></div>
```

If you have a bad HTML that use unique `id` multiple time, that way you can fix them:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('div[id="app"]')]
  .forEach(($app, i) => $app.setAttribute('id', `app-${i+1}`));
```

```css
#app {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#app-1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#app-2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#app-3 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the effort. You added class name nicely. But I want to do same for id so that I can get unique ids. For example, your code add new class `app app-1` but I want to add numbers after my ids. so the div should look like this 
`<div id="app-1"></div>
<div id="app-2"></div>
<div id="app-3"></div>`

Comment: I added the example below is for `id`, you are free to update the code, are improve your question